# Keep showing marquee content after it has been scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

I have marquee and there is a text inside it, what I want is to show the start of the text when the start of the text is hidden or begin scrolled
this is the markup code

```
<div class="eventBar">
  <span>Events</span>
  <marquee style="width:93%;float:right" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:20px;margin:0 10px 0;vertical-align:-3px">   
     This is event number 44
    <img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:20px;margin:0 10px 0;vertical-align:-3px">   
     This is event number 33
    <img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:20px;margin:0 10px 0;vertical-align:-3px">   
     This is event number 22
    <img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:20px;margin:0 10px 0;vertical-align:-3px">   
     This is event number 11
  </marquee>
</div>
```

How it looks now  :  [Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cfF7.png)

This is how I want it to be and some explanation  : [Marquee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omCST.png)

Thanks a lot for heling me.

Answer (score 0):

Marquee is deprecated for many years now ..  You'll have to find a javascript solution for this.  Here is a repo what might be a solution: https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee I haven't tested it myself

Comment: But it's still working on the browsers..
I have seen the link you posted and it's not helpful at all,
at the end I want to apply the idea of the marquee that I visualized in the main post pictures (pls check them). and it doesn't matter the way to do it.

Thanks in advance.